# Reusable enumeration in mib files

Tags: enums, snmp, mib

There is a way to enumerate values in mib files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base) such as 
http://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv1/using_mibs_in_applns/enumintegers.html
however is it possible to write such enumeration and reuse it throughout the mib to avoid duplicate enumerations throughout the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a chance to carefully read SNMPv2-TC,

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2579.txt

you will see that there are already common enum types defined, such as TruthValue.

```
TruthValue ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS       current
    DESCRIPTION
            "Represents a boolean value."
    SYNTAX       INTEGER { true(1), false(2) }
```

By importing such enum definitions in your MIB document or define your own, you can use/reuse them throughout the file.